# Composer PHP Install a bundle inside a parent bundles src folder

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to create a similar bundle structure like Symfony or Sylius. These have a parent package with a set of child bundles in a sub folder.
EG symfony/framework-standard-edition puts its bundles in Symfony/Component and Sylius puts them in Sylius/Src 
These are private bundles stored on a private git repo. So I can't use packagist.

The plan is to have a folder structure like:

```
/vendor/MyNamespace/PackageA/src/BundleA
/vendor/MyNamespace/PackageA/src/BundleB
/vendor/MyNamespace/PackageA/src/BundleC
/vendor/MyNamespace/BundleD
/vendor/MyNamespace/BundleE
```

So bundles A - C are contained in package A.
Package A requires Bundles A - C. So I would just need to require MyNamespace/PackageA and the three packages would be installed into PackageA.

I've tried setting the target-dir but its putting BundleA inside

```
/vendor/MyNamespace/BundleA/PackageA/BundleA
```

As this is a private set of repos, should  I to use a satis to handle them?

Answer (score 1):

For private repos use satis or just state where your private (git) repos are using `repositories` http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository configuration.

I would use for each of your packages separate package and I would drop idea to play with target-dir, as target-dir is deprecated http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#target-dir

But this can be helpful to you: http://seld.be/

Comment: Yes I'm currently using repositories to list my private repos. I'm having difficulty with changing the paths.  I want to include a set of bundles (Or components) into a parent bundle. EG /vendor/MynameSpace/src would include BundleA and BundleB

Comment: Why do you want that? What is the benefit of it? Composer is working using flat structure, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: It would tidy up the structure of my bundles. Symfony and Sylius have lots of bundles that can either be used individually or be used as a whole. I would like to do the same. Lets say I have a bunch of bundles that deal with car parts, like a wheelBundle and doorBundle. What I want to do is to contain these two inside a carBundle. They would be held in vendor/CarBundle/src/WheelBundle and vendor/carBundle /src/doorbundle The car bundle would act like a container (Like the symfony framework bundle) for these components.

Comment: These bundles are stored in separate repos. I was hoping to ignore the contents of carBundle/src/ and composer would move doorBundle into that directory.  However I'm not so sure that this is going to work.  I may need to re think this.

Comment: If I look on symfony, it is always in separate directories. vendor/symfony/<component>/Symfony/. It is not instaled in the same component. I think you are overengineering this.

Comment: Agreed, they are in separate component directories but they all live under a single parent directory. - Symfony. So ideally I would have vendor/carBundle/<component>/CarBundle/ Not sure how I could do this

Comment: But you are right, it is probably done through target-dir, but it is depracated in composer, please try to read this http://seld.be/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44986/discussion-between-pfwd-and-jasir)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution using git subtree.
Splitting off the child components into their own repositories and adding them as sub tress of a parent repository.
EG:

```
/Car.git (Parent repository)
/Door.git (Child component of car)
/Engine.git (Child component of car)
```

In Car:

```
/Car/src/
       DoorBundle
       EngineBundle
   /bin (Contains some generic commands)
   /composer.json (Contains requirements for Door and engine)
```

Door doesn't require engine and engine doesn't require door.  But Car requires both.

By using the git subtree I have control over the parent folder structure.  Also using target-dir (haven't tried it with psr-4 yet) I can tell composer where to look for my child compoents.

Another benefit is re-usability and isolation of the child components. I can just use Door or Engine on their own. Perhaps one day I will create a truck that needs another engine or something.